# Trying to show offsets using Cartopy

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to build a map using the OpenStreetMap tile server substrate, which is based on: control points, profile points 1 and 2 which are combined with lines of different colors. For each of the profile points, directions (azimuth in degrees) and offset (value) in the form of an arrow supposed to be shown. Data for the code can be found at the link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1REX9ebrYR701IGZEWO1zf0St-6lA7M1r?usp=sharing

When executing the code, the direction (azimuth in degrees) and offsets (value) in the form of arrows are not displayed. Changes to scale_factor values ​​are not working. Tell me, please, what is wrong? I can't find any error. Thanks in advance for your reply!

I have 3 versions of the code and they all don't work.

Version 1

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cartopy import crs as ccrs
import shapefile
from cartopy.io.img_tiles import OSM
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch

shpfile = shapefile.Reader("/Users/Desktop/tdata/tdata")

fields = [x[0] for x in shpfile.fields[1:]]

points = {'base': [], 'profile1': [], 'profile2': []}
for item in shpfile.iterShapeRecords():
    kind = item.record[fields.index('kind')]
    position = item.shape.points[0]
    points[kind].append((position, dict(zip(fields, item.record))))

tiles_provider = OSM()

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16))

ax = plt.axes(projection=tiles_provider.crs)

ax.set_extent([shpfile.bbox[0]-0.1, shpfile.bbox[2]+0.1,
               shpfile.bbox[1]-0.1, shpfile.bbox[3]+0.1], ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_image(tiles_provider, 11)

def draw_arrow(ax, point, angle, length, scale_factor=1, **kwargs):
    angle_rad = np.deg2rad(angle)
    dx = scale_factor * length * np.cos(angle_rad)
    dy = scale_factor * length * np.sin(angle_rad)
    arrow = FancyArrowPatch(point, (point[0]+dx, point[1]+dy), connectionstyle="arc3,rad=.5", **kwargs)
    ax.add_patch(arrow)

for point, data in points['base']:
    ax.plot(point[0], point[1], marker='o', markersize=5, color='red', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

for i, (point, data) in enumerate(points['profile1']):
    if i > 0:
        prev_point = points['profile1'][i-1][0]
        ax.plot([prev_point[0], point[0]], [prev_point[1], point[1]], color='blue', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    draw_arrow(ax, point, data['az'], data['value'], color='blue', scale_factor=0.001, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

for i, (point, data) in enumerate(points['profile2']):
    if i > 0:
        prev_point = points['profile2'][i-1][0]
        ax.plot([prev_point[0], point[0]], [prev_point[1], point[1]], color='green', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    draw_arrow(ax, point, data['az'], data['value'], color='green', scale_factor=0.001, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

Version 2

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cartopy import crs as ccrs
import shapefile
from cartopy.io.img_tiles import OSM
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch

shpfile = shapefile.Reader("/Users/Desktop/tdata/tdata")

fields = [x[0] for x in shpfile.fields[1:]]

points = {'base': [], 'profile1': [], 'profile2': []}
for item in shpfile.iterShapeRecords():
    kind = item.record[fields.index('kind')]
    position = item.shape.points[0]
    points[kind].append((position, dict(zip(fields, item.record))))

tiles_provider = OSM()

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16))

ax = plt.axes(projection=tiles_provider.crs)

ax.set_extent([shpfile.bbox[0]-0.1, shpfile.bbox[2]+0.1,
               shpfile.bbox[1]-0.1, shpfile.bbox[3]+0.1], ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_image(tiles_provider, 11)

def draw_arrow(ax, point, angle, length, scale_factor=1, **kwargs):
    angle_rad = np.deg2rad(angle)
    dx = scale_factor * length * np.cos(angle_rad)
    dy = scale_factor * length * np.sin(angle_rad)
    point_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree().transform_point(point[0], point[1], ax.projection)
    arrow = FancyArrowPatch(point_proj, (point_proj[0] + dx, point_proj[1] + dy), connectionstyle="arc3,rad=.5", **kwargs)
    ax.add_patch(arrow)

for point, data in points['base']:
    ax.plot(point[0], point[1], marker='o', markersize=5, color='red', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

for i, (point, data) in enumerate(points['profile1']):
    if i > 0:
        prev_point = points['profile1'][i-1][0]
        ax.plot([prev_point[0], point[0]], [prev_point[1], point[1]], color='blue', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        draw_arrow(ax, point, data['az'], data['value'], scale_factor=10, color='blue', transform=ax.projection)

for i, (point, data) in enumerate(points['profile2']):
    if i > 0:
        prev_point = points['profile2'][i-1][0]
        ax.plot([prev_point[0], point[0]], [prev_point[1], point[1]], color='green', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        draw_arrow(ax, point, data['az'], data['value'], scale_factor=10, color='green', transform=ax.projection)

plt.show()
```

Version 3

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cartopy import crs as ccrs
import shapefile
from cartopy.io.img_tiles import OSM
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch
from cartopy.mpl.geoaxes import GeoAxes
from matplotlib.transforms import offset_copy

shpfile = shapefile.Reader("/Users/Desktop/tdata/tdata")

fields = [x[0] for x in shpfile.fields[1:]]

points = {'base': [], 'profile1': [], 'profile2': []}
for item in shpfile.iterShapeRecords():
    kind = item.record[fields.index('kind')]
    position = item.shape.points[0]
    points[kind].append((position, dict(zip(fields, item.record))))

tiles_provider = OSM()

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16))

ax = plt.axes(projection=tiles_provider.crs)

ax.set_extent([shpfile.bbox[0]-0.1, shpfile.bbox[2]+0.1,
               shpfile.bbox[1]-0.1, shpfile.bbox[3]+0.1], ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_image(tiles_provider, 11)

def draw_arrow(ax, point, angle, length, color, scale_factor=1, linewidth=1.5, **kwargs):
    angle_rad = np.deg2rad(angle)
    dx = scale_factor * length * np.cos(angle_rad)
    dy = scale_factor * length * np.sin(angle_rad)

    proj_arrow = ccrs.PlateCarree().transform_point(point[0]+dx, point[1]+dy, ax.projection)
    proj_point = ccrs.PlateCarree().transform_point(point[0], point[1], ax.projection)

    arrow = FancyArrowPatch(proj_point, proj_arrow, arrowstyle='->', mutation_scale=20, linewidth=linewidth, color=color, **kwargs)
    GeoAxes.add_patch(ax, arrow)

for point, data in points['base']:
    ax.plot(point[0], point[1], marker='o', markersize=5, color='red', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

for i, (point, data) in enumerate(points['profile1']):
    if i > 0:
        prev_point = points['profile1'][i-1][0]
        ax.plot([prev_point[0], point[0]], [prev_point[1], point[1]], color='blue', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    draw_arrow(ax, point, data['az'], data['value'], color='blue', scale_factor=0.001)

for i, (point, data) in enumerate(points['profile2']):
    if i > 0:
        prev_point = points['profile2'][i-1][0]
        ax.plot([prev_point[0], point[0]], [prev_point[1], point[1]], color='green', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    draw_arrow(ax, point, data['az'], data['value'], color='green', scale_factor=0.001)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you include `shpfile` (or a subset of it) in your question?

Comment: Data that i used https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1REX9ebrYR701IGZEWO1zf0St-6lA7M1r?usp=sharing